# Using IF statement in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using the IF statement like this:

```
ALTER proc spGetUserLevelCode 
( 
    @strLoginID VARCHAR(20) = '', @outdata int  output
) AS

if(select level_code 
    from org_person with(nolock) 
    where person_code = @strLoginID) = 'CA40'
```

as you can see, I extend `CA50`, `CA60` like this adding behind `'CA40' or 'CA50' or 'CA60'`
but there is an error

How can I use additional condition in IF condition?

Comment: Look into this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182587.aspx But in the meantime, perhaps your `SELECT` returns more than one row? What error did you get? Kindly post it..

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
IN ('CA40','CA50','CA60' )
```

Or

```
 LIKE 'CA[4-6]0'
```

Not `= 'CA40' or 'CA50' or 'CA60'`

Comment: +1 for the SQL LIKE pattern - IN is more readable, but the LIKE demonstrates a neat additional way of looking at the problem, plus a useful demo of a feature of SQL Server's string matching :-)

Comment: thanks for your reply.even though It's beginners' question :) Finally I made it

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd prefer to use an exists in this case

```
ALTER proc spGetUserLevelCode 
( 
    @strLoginID VARCHAR(20) = '', @outdata int  output
) AS

if exists(select *
    from org_person with(nolock) 
    where person_code = @strLoginID
    AND level_code IN ('CA40','CA50','CA60') )
BEGIN
    --DO SOMETHING
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either way as below:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
   FROM org_person WITH(NOLOCK) 
   WHERE person_code = @strLoginID
        AND level_code IN ('CA40','CA50','CA60') )
BEGIN
  -- Other statement goes here
END
```

OR

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
   FROM org_person WITH(NOLOCK) 
   WHERE person_code = @strLoginID
        AND level_code LIKE 'CA[4-6]0' )
BEGIN
  -- Other statement goes here
END
```